# schema version mismatch cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I am trying to drop a materialized view on Cassandra and facing the below issue:

```
> drop materialized view XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX;
OperationTimedOut: errors={'10.10.101.10': 'Request timed out while waiting for 
schema agreement. See Session.execute[_async](timeout) and 
Cluster.max_schema_agreement_wait.'}, last_host=10.10.101.10
Warning: schema version mismatch detected; check the schema versions of your nodes
in system.local and system.peers.
```

Answer (score 5):

To investigate schema disagreement, try running `nodetool describecluster`:

```
$ nodetool describecluster
Cluster Information:
    Name: StackOverflowTest
    Snitch: org.apache.cassandra.locator.DynamicEndpointSnitch
    Partitioner: org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner
    Schema versions:
        276ea081-1204-3bee-a92a-2171a68bd3a9: [10.1.2.3, 10.1.2.4, 10.6.1.4, 10.1.8.2, 10.1.8.7, 10.6.1.3]

        1f7d8b47-22d3-3210-b385-b2cdeb9c69e6: [10.6.1.5]
```

Notice that most of my nodes agree on the first schema version, but `10.6.1.5` has its own schema version.  In this case, try to do a graceful restart of the offending node's Cassandra process (`10.6.1.5` in this case).  When the node comes back up, it will negotiate schema version which should resolve the issue.

Comment: tried restarting the process on the offending node multiple times but it still doesn't solve the issue. Any idea what could be done (except removing the node)? p.s. had to delete the commit logs on the offeding node because was running into errors while restarting it

Answer (score 2):

You can check your cluster with `nodetool describecluster` which gives you some output about every nodes schema version. I guess you will see one or a few nodes out of the majority.

Most often this can be easily fixed by restarting this nodes.

Here an example of one of my clusters (without any error in schema versions):

```
Cluster Information:
        Name: TestCluster
        Snitch: org.apache.cassandra.locator.DynamicEndpointSnitch
        Partitioner: org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner
        Schema versions:
                50219260-24ad-320f-9bd3-9ed0b207e2c6: [x.x.x.9, x.x.x.9, x.x.x.168, x.x.x.14, x.x.x.23, x.x.x.11, x.x.x.180, x.x.x.240, x.x.x.80, x.x.x.136, x.x.x.209, x.x.x.151]
```